# Result Value on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want all the value with the same ID to be on the same line in the query below. I do not know how to go about it. Please help

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE 
             (ID INT,
              Day1 Varchar(10), Day2 Varchar(10), Day3 Varchar(10),
              Day4 Varchar(10), Day5 Varchar(10), Day6 Varchar(10),
              Day7 Varchar(10), Day8 Varchar(10),
              Day9 Varchar(10), Day10 Varchar(10)
             )

INSERT INTO @Tab 
VALUES
    (1,'R','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (1,'NULL','R','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (1,'NULL','NULL','C','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (1,'NULL','NULL','NULL','D','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (1,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (1,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','V','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (1,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','Y','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (1,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','R','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'R','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','C','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','K','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','V','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','R','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','R','NULL','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','K','NULL'),
    (2,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','C'),
    (3,'R','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','R','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','R','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','NULL','C','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','W','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','V','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','A','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','D','NULL','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','W','NULL'),
    (3,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','Y')

SELECT * 
FROM @Tab
```

The output I want

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you **really** want to insert the **string value** of `'NULL'` into almost each column - or did you intend to insert `NULL` (the *absence* of a value - **without** any single quotes!) for most columns?

Comment: @marc_s this is just a sample data. it is the result of the query. i mimic my result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation function on each column :

```
SELECT t.id,
       MAX(t.Day1) as Day1,
       MAX(t.day2) as Day2,
       ..
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Though your output is wrong, I assume it's a typo.